# Gigabit Ethernet not working between two computers

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I have two Linux PCs A and B connected:

- PC A (`Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)`) is configured for method "Shared to other computers" in the IPv4 tab of the KDE network configuration (NetworkManager under the hood, for both ends).
- PC B (`Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)`) is using the automatic setting.

The problem is that the connection will only work as 100Mbps half duplex.

Yet, according to `ethtool`, both ends support `10baseT/Half`, `10baseT/Full`, `100baseT/Half`, `100baseT/Full` and `1000baseT/Full` and the cable I use is cat6.

When I disable automatic negotiation and force full duplex (whether that is 10, 100 or 1000Mbps), connection fails. Automatic negotiation always lead to 100Mbps half duplex to be used.

Changing cables and keeping them away from potential electrical noise sources (AC) does not help.

I suspect that the issue might be related to PC B. What could that be? Is there anything I can do to debug this issue further?

Comment: Please check `ethtool` output (or, better, edit the question to include it) for the *advertised* modes during autonegation (both local and remote; for both sides). If there are some cabling/connector issues, often the hardware will refuse to advertise 1000baseT/Full.

Comment: 1000baseT/Full was advertised properly, however I have found the problem to be a physical issue on PC B's port.

Comment: It was properly advertised from both sides, even though the pin assignment was messed up? That's interesting.

Comment: It was because the pins were bent, so the physical connection was bad. According to a pinout website, pins 4, 5, 7, 8 are required for a gigabit connection, otherwise it falls back to 100Mbps.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but normally the hardware detects that, and stops advertising this mode. Though it looks like Qualcomm Atheros hardware doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is a problem on the port of PC B. After trying to move some pins, I managed to make it work at 1Gbps/Full, however there is still some connectivity issue (because the pins are fairly messed up, which I have yet to solve).

Problem "solved", though.